# How do I detect proper nouns in the Google NLP API?

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp

Apologies if this isn't totally clear - I'm a Python copy-the-code-and-try-to-make-it-work developer.

I'm using the Google NLP API in Python 2.7.

When I use analyze_entities(), I can get and print the name, entity type and salience.

Mentions is supposed to contain the noun type: PROPER or COMMON, per this page:

https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/Entity#EntityMention

I can't get mention type from the returned dictionary.

Here's my hideous code:

```
def entities_text(text, client):
"""Detects entities in the text."""
language_client = client

# Instantiates a plain text document.
document = language_client.document_from_text(text)

# Detects entities in the document. You can also analyze HTML with:
#   document.doc_type == language.Document.HTML
entities = document.analyze_entities()
return entities
articles = os.listdir('articles')
for f in articles:
    language_client = language.Client()
    fname = "articles/" + f
    thisfile = open(fname,'r')
    content = thisfile.read()
    entities = entities_text(content, language_client)
    for e in entities:
        name = e.name.strip()
        type = e.entity_type.strip()
        if e.name.strip()[0].isupper() and len(e.name.strip()) > 2:
            print name, type, e.salience, e.mentions
```

That returns this:

RELATED OTHER 0.0019081507 [u'RELATED']
Zoe 3 PERSON 0.0016676666 [u'Zoe  3']

Where the value in [] is the mentions.

If I try to get mentions.type, I get an attribute not found error.

I'd appreciate any input.

Comment: From the source code, it looks like the Google Python library strips out the "type" value from the mentions...https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/a02ac500548cf9fc37f4d81033e696a0efb53f99/language/google/cloud/language/entity.py#L106-L107

Comment: Well, dang. Is there a good reason, or should I just hack away and put the value back?

Comment: I don't know why they did that...you'd have to ask one of the devs. You could always fork the repo and hack at it...make a PR if it seems useful to other folks.